# Reset Appearance for button font conditionally

Tags: ios, swift, uiappearance

My App supports two languages. Language can be changed within the app. For buttons I have set font through appearance property in app delegate. I need two different fonts based on language. I am setting it like,

```
if language == "en" {
    UIButton.appearance().titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18)
} else {
    UIButton.appearance().titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Cairo", size: 18)!
}
```

When language is changed then I am invoking above code but it looks like it sets to the one which gets called first time at the time of app launching.

I followed few threads & it suggests to handle it manually on each controller for relevant UI components. But looks quite lengthy work.

Any clues to sort out my issue where I can set appearance based on my language?

Comment: Setting the appearance only affects buttons created after it is set. It does not change any buttons that already exist.

Comment: Which app delegate method are you putting this in? Where is `language` coming from here?

Comment: @BergQuester, I have created separate method for this & for first time I am calling it from appDidFinishLaunching. "language" is locally saved variable where I am keeping track of currently selected language.